# Asynchronous mail receiving with Spring Boot and Spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to receive emails from gmail server and then process them somehow. So every time when new email arrives to the mail server, my application should download it and process it, it means call other services asynchronously which will be registered as listeners.

I'm quite new in spring integration and I don't fully understand how does it work or if it is correct.

**1) So far, I have this code** -- I'm able to read all emails but I'm not sure if they are processed **asynchronously** or not or if it is a correct way?

ListeningExample class

```
@Configuration
public class ListeningExample {

    @Bean
    public HeaderMapper<MimeMessage> mailHeaderMapper() {
        return new DefaultMailHeaderMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow imapMailFlow() {    
        IntegrationFlow flow =  IntegrationFlows
                .from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter("imap://user:pwd@imap.gmail.com/INBOX")
                                .userFlag("testSIUserFlag")
                                .javaMailProperties(javaMailProperties()),
                        e -> e.autoStartup(true)
                                .poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(5000)))dostane to detailni zpravy
                .transform(Mail.toStringTransformer())
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue("imapChannel"))
                .get();
        return flow;
     }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {

        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(1000));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }
}
```

MailRecieverService class

```
@Service
public class MailRecieverService {

    private List<EmailAction> services;

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "imapChannel")
    public MessageHandler processNewEmail() {
        MessageHandler messageHandler = new MessageHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(org.springframework.messaging.Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                System.out.println("New email:" + message.toString());

                //Processing emails do with them something..
                for (EmailAction emailAction : services) {
                    emailAction.performAction(null);
                }

            }
        };
        return messageHandler;
    }

}
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Main.class);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Main.class);
        builder.headless(false).run(args);
    }

}
```

**2) Is there also a possibility in spring boot to move/delete emails, create folders, and do other actions with an email account or do I have to use `javax.mail` library on my own?** 
If yes, could you provide some examples?

Comment: as per my knowledge the spring boot dont provide any direct API to do it, you have to use mail libraries

Comment: Did you check the transactions part of the documentation? The example moves a message after it processes it successfully (the transaction commits). https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html#mail-tx-sync

Comment: @Pauli Can you provide the full source code of your application ?

Answer (score 0):

Your integration flow is correct. The IMAP Inbound Channel Adapter is async by its nature and it spawns a thread to loop new emails. However if you worry about your `for (EmailAction emailAction : services) {`, then you need to think making this part as async by yourself. You definitely can use a `PublishSubscribeChannel` with an `Executor` and several subscribers for those services to really process the same email message in those services in parallel.

All the other stuff about delete, create and other email management operations are out of Enterprise Integration Patterns scope. Therefore there is no any high level Spring API to do those operation from the application. Consider to use Java Mail API directly: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Project_Documentation

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` is asynchronous.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html#mail-inbound

To do an action after the processing of the message has finished you can wrap it in a transaction, and perform an action after commit:

In the example of the documentation it is moving the email to another folder.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html#mail-tx-sync